# How much would it cost to take a train from Krakow to Prague, Prague to Munich, Munich to Hamburg, and Hamburg to Warsaw?

Tags: trains, germany, poland, czech-republic, central-europe

I was thinking about purchasing the tickets at the local stations. I wanted to spend three weeks in Poland and a week in Prague, Munich, and Hamburg. I set aside $300 for each train itinerary but I'm not sure if that's enough.

Comment: If you're talking about 300 USD for each leg then you should have left some pocket money :)

Comment: Nope, 300 CAD...

Comment: I wanted to emphasize the part about 300$ for *each* leg.

Comment: @Kris: no big difference these days...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You *may* be able to make a [**Eurail Pass**](http://www.eurail.com/)  work for you.

[Oh so dear but oh so wonderful global pass](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes/global-pass)

[Regional passes here](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes/regional-pass)

eg [Germany Poland here](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes/regional-pass/germany-poland)

Eureka! - There are [**"Select Passes"**](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes/select-pass/3-countries) allowing 3 or 4 or 5 countries of your pecification. These were not shown in the general menu.

---

[Eurail 2013 routes map](http://www.eurail.com/sites/all/files/eurail.com/downloads/2013/eurailmap-2013.pdf) PDF download.  Large and impressive.

---

**Regional Passes:**

These are usually 2 country passes allowing N days of travel within an overall period. Adding the extra country may make individual pricing cheaper.

Austria-Croatia-Slovenia
Austria-Czech Republic
Austria-Germany
Austria-Hungary
Austria-Switzerland
Benelux-France
Benelux-Germany
Croatia-Slovenia-Hungary
Czech Republic-Germany
Denmark-Germany
Denmark-Sweden
Finland-Sweden
France-Germany
France-Italy
France-Spain
France-Switzerland
Germany-Poland
Germany-Switzerland
Greece-Italy
Hungary-Romania
Italy-Spain
Norway-Sweden
Portugal-Spain
Scandinavia

Comment: Global pass does not include Poland by the way.

Comment: @Kris Polands is off the globe?  Weird.

Answer (score 10):

I did some checks on prices for you. Prices are from Bahn.de. Please verify this yourself as well.

- Krakow - Prague: $37 (this one's from Rome2rio.com - Bahn wouldn't give it up)
- Prague - Munich: <strike>$120</strike> $87
- Munich - Hamburg: <strike>$200</strike> $102
- Hamburg - Warsaw: <strike>$200</strike> $102 (possibly cheaper possible, since these are ICE train)

Total: CAD$328

A 5 day [Eurail Select](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes/select-pass/3-countries) pass would be $320. So based on these prices, it's a pretty close call.

Comment: These prices are high. I found a combination for roughly 200 USD. Moreover if you buy a Eurail pass you will still have to pay extra for sleepers, seat reservation and hig speed trains (ICE).

Comment: I would no use rome2rio to get a serious price quote.

Comment: Hi Marcel, care to expand on where you got the combination price quote from? Happy to update my answer if there's better information.

Comment: I've re-checked the prices on bahn and there is quite a difference. In fact, such that you'd probably say buying individual tickets will work better.

Marcel, can you elaborate on the combination ticket?

Comment: You should add that with a EUrail pass, you have considerably more flexibility.

Answer (score 8):

300 USD should even be enough to cover all these itineraries. To know the exact price for tains to and from destinations in Germany, you can have a look at http://www.bahn.de

For the tickets from Krakow to Prague you can have a look at http://www.polrail.com . Or try at the station in Krakow. The Czech railways only allow booking into the other direction.

The price eventually depends on how early you book, how much comfort you choose and how flexible/restrictive tickets you buy.

I know that there are Interrail or Eurail passes. They might be worth a look only if you are less than 26 years old. But even in that case, you will probably be better off by buying point to point tickets.

As an example, here are some quotes for 2nd class travel, with a departure in three weeks, on a weekday.

Krakow – Prague : 76 USD (www.polrail.com)

Prague – Munich :  25 USD (www.cd.cz)

Munich – Hamburg : 88 USD (www.bahn.de)

Hamburg – Warsaw :  55 USD (www.bahn.de)

= 244 USD

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered a Eurail pass? This allows travel on European railways for a fixed set price. Current prices start at USD $313 (for your entire trip) for those three countries if you are 25 or younger.

http://www.eurail.com/

Comment: I was looking into that. Don't they expire? For example when it says 5 days in 2 months, can I use it for 5 separate trips? Or is it 5 days from when you purchase the pass?

Comment: I would refer to the website for those details. I believe it means you can travel on trains for 5 days at anytime during the 2 months. The pass I had (10 years ago) allowed unlimited travel for 1 month, however today there seem to be many options.

Comment: This passvis for travel on 5 separate says during two months. The two month period starts on your first day of travel. The five days need not be consecutive.

Answer (score 2):

A pass like the Eurail Pass (and the Interrail Pass) was once a great way to travel around Europe. You could just hop on and off trains at leasure.
However, these days are mostly gone. Many long distance trains require reservations, which mean you need to go to the station to get them anyway, and often there are limited contingents for pass holders. 
In practice it is now best to just buy long segments online in advance to take advantage of advance purchase deals, and for short trips just to buy them locally at the station on the day of travel.

Comment: The problem I have with booking tickets online in adavance is that I'm not exactly sure how long I plan to stay in each city. I have a rough idea but nothing's set in stone.